# Проблема в коде VB.NET. Поиск числа по указанным параметрам. Не выполняет цикл Do until

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

Найти наименьшее натуральное число, которое делится на 17, оканчивается на 17 и имеет сумму цифр 17.

Сделал программу, но почему-то Цикл вида `Do While` не выполняется. Помогите решить проблему, а заодно и с решением  поставленной задачи.

Выполняю в *Visual Studio 2017*

Sub Main()

```
    Dim n, sum, nu As Integer
    sum = 0
    n = 17 ' наименьшее число, которое делится на 17, оканчивается на 17, но не имеет сумму цифр равную 17'
    Console.WriteLine("Найти наименьшее натуральное число, которое делится на 17, оканчивается на 17 и имеет сумму цифр 17.")
    Do Until n Mod 17 = 0 And n Mod 100 = 17 And sum = 17
        n = n + 100 'Добавляю по 100, чтобы сохранить на конце 17'
        n = nu
        Do While nu > 0 'здесь нахожу сумму чисел'
            sum = sum + (nu Mod 10)
            nu = nu \ 10
        Loop
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("Наименьшее число: " & n)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: Вместо `n = nu` (вообще зачем это здесь?) напишите `nu = 0`.

Comment: Так а где у вас переменная `nu` получает хоть какое-то ненулевое значение? Как она была изначально нулем, так и осталась. С чего бы это вдруг ваш цикл будет выполняться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Число 15317

```
Sub Main()
    Dim n, sum, nu As Integer
    n = 17
    Console.WriteLine ("ищем")

    Do
        If n Mod 17 = 0 Then  ' делится на 17'
            nu = n
            sum = 0

            Do While nu > 0
                sum = sum + (nu Mod 10) ' сумма чисел'
                nu = nu \ 10
            Loop
        End If

        If sum <> 17 Then n = n + 100 ' оканчивается на 17'
    Loop Until sum = 17

    Console.WriteLine ("Наименьшее число: " & n)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Сократить вычисления:

- перед циклом определить необходимую сумму за вычетом суммы чисел указанной константы: `x = 17 - (1 + 7) = 9`
- в цикле суммировать цифры числа `nu = n / 100`